# How does active software protection dongles work?

Tags: dongle, software-protection

I have seen the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_protection_dongle) which is a bit sketchy on the details.
I would like to know, in addition to general principles of operation, some practical details like:

Are they limited to compiled native programs or they can be employed with Java/Dot Net etc?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check with the manufacturer of the dongle on what languages they support.  Usually for Windows OS a DLL is supplied that can talk to the dongle and any language that can call into a DLL can use the dongle.

Comment: My concern is whether these solutions will be able to protect non-native code adequately.